# An error occured while executing doInBackground() line 112

Tags: java, android

I sometimes get the following crash report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:154)
at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171)
at com.package.class.doMoreStuff(Student2.java:432)
at com.package.class$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Student2.java:608)
at com.package.class.Student2$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Student2.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
... 4 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:112)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:90)
at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:154)
at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171)
at com.package.class.doMoreStuff(Student2.java:432)
at com.package.class$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Student2.java:608)
at com.package.class.$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(Student2.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I know the problem is happening on line 112. The code on that line is:

```
    if(isTablet(context))
    {
        new online().execute();
    }
    else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)
                {
                    new online().execute();
                }
            }
        }, 200);
    }
```

Line 112 is the `else`, I am getting the app to check if it is a tablet, if not rotate the screen, wait a small bit then continue. I had to set a delay on it otherwise it would continue before the app fully rotating and would crash. I'm not quiet sure what is causing the app to crash on only a devices.

I just noticed that I had the `if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2)` line there, that wouldn't be the cause of it, would it?

EDIT:
Line 432 is

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(aBuffer);
```

Comment: What is at line 432 in `doMoreStuff`? That's where your error is. 112 is in the json library it seems

Comment: I have edited in what line 432 is. I think I found what the problem is though (I could be wrong). The `aBuffer` was declared with the rest of the variables, but I only initialised it inside section of code, that doesn't always run. So that variable is initialised where it is declared.

Comment: Are you sure that is line 432 of `Student2.java`? Because that line shouldn't throw a `NPE` but could cause one somewhere else. Anyway, you probably either want to take some action if `aBuffer` is `null` there or initialize it somewhere where it will be called every time.

Comment: There is a piece of code just above that that is a try block which initialises the `aBuffer`. Sometimes the try block fails which means that it doesn't get initialised. I have changed it so it will be initialised every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I had wasn't caused by some code on line 112, it was caused by code on line 432:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(aBuffer);
```

The app was crashing when the variable `aBuffer` wasn't being initialised. It was being declared with the rest of the variables, but not initialised. It was only being initialised in a try block that in certain circumstances was being executed. I changed the code so `aBuffer` would be initialised and fixed the problem.